# Problems writing code for an R DT summarizing result across multiple studies with collapsable child rows

Tags: javascript, r, r-markdown, dt

I'm trying to make an interactive table summarizing the top result of an outcome tested in multiple studies, and I would also like the user to access more detailed results via child rows.  Only the "top" model with the smallest p-value is shown in the main table.

Right now I have the relevant results into two data frames:  1. top result only, and 2. detailed results.  I am merging these and nesting based on the top results which I want to display.

```
library(DT)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

# == Create dataframe with results to summarize


allresults <- list(c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study1", "heartAttack_v1", "ageSex", 1e-6), 
                   c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study1", "heartAttack_v2", "ageSexBmi", 0.001), 
                   c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study2", "heartAttack_v1", "ageSex", 0.05), 
                   c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study2", "heartAttack_v2", "ageSexBmi", "0.2"), 
                   c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study3", "heartAttack_v1", "ageSex", "0.005"), 
                   c( "Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study1", "cancer_v1", "ageSex", 0.6), 
                   c( "Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study1", "cancer_v2", "ageSex", 0.05), 
                   c("Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study2", "cancer_v1", "ageSexBmi", 0.2), 
                   c("Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study2", "cancer_v2", "ageSex", 0.01), 
                   c("Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study3", "cancer_v1", "ageSexBmi", 0.002))

df <- as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(allresults)))
colnames(df) <- c("outcome.bestOf", "study1.bestOf", "study2.bestOf", "study3.bestOf", "studyName", "outcome", "model", "pvalue")
rownames(df)<-NULL



# == Collapse to display top-result table, one row per outcome
nest_fields <- c("outcome.bestOf", "study1.bestOf", "study2.bestOf", "study3.bestOf") 
dt <- df %>%
  nest(-nest_fields)

# == Add (+) column
data <- dt %>% {bind_cols(data_frame(' ' = rep('&oplus;',nrow(.))),.)}

# == Get dynamic info and strings
# == code via: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/issues/9

nested_columns         <- which(sapply(data,class)=="list") %>% setNames(NULL)
not_nested_columns     <- which(!(seq_along(data) %in% c(1,nested_columns)))
not_nested_columns_str <- not_nested_columns %>% paste(collapse="] + '_' + d[") %>% paste0("d[",.,"]")

# == The callback
# == Turn rows into child rows and remove from parent
callback <- paste0("
                   table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});

                   // Format data object (the nested table) into another table
                   var format = function(d) {
                   if(d != null){ 
                   var result = ('<table id=\"child_' + ",not_nested_columns_str," + '\">').replace('.','_') + '<thead><tr>'
                   for (var col in d[",nested_columns,"]){
                   result += '<th>' + col + '</th>'
                   }
                   result += '</tr></thead></table>'
                   return result
                   }else{
                   return '';
                   }
                   }

                   var format_datatable = function(d) {
                   var dataset = [];
                   for (i = 0; i < + d[",nested_columns,"]['cohort'].length; i++) {
                   var datarow = [];
                   for (var col in d[",nested_columns,"]){
                   datarow.push(d[",nested_columns,"][col][i])
                   }
                   dataset.push(datarow)
                   }
                   var subtable = $(('table#child_' + ",not_nested_columns_str,").replace('.','_')).DataTable({
                   'data': dataset,
                   'autoWidth': true, 
                   'deferRender': true, 
                   'info': false, 
                   'lengthChange': false, 
                   'ordering': true, 
                   'paging': false, 
                   'scrollX': false, 
                   'scrollY': false, 
                   'searching': false 
                   });
                   };

                   table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
                   var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
                   if (row.child.isShown()) {
                   row.child.hide();
                   td.html('&oplus;');
                   } else {
                   row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                   td.html('&CircleMinus;');
                   format_datatable(row.data())
                   }
                   });"
                  )


# == the Display DT
datatable(
  data,
  escape = FALSE,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0,nested_columns) ), # Hide row numbers and nested columns
      list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1) # turn first column into control column
    )
  ),
  callback = JS(callback)
)
```

This code creates the summary table that I want as a tibble, but no child row data appears when I expand:

[image: childless_tibble]

However, if I access the child rows programmatically, they seem to contain the data I want:

```
> data[data$outcome.bestOf=="Cancer", 'data'][[1]]
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  studyName outcome    model     pvalue
  <fct>     <fct>      <fct>     <fct> 
1 study1    cancer_v1  ageSex    0.6   
2 study1    cancer_v2  ageSex    0.05  
3 study2    cancer_v1  ageSexBmi 0.2   
4 study2    cancer_v2  ageSex    0.01  
5 study3    cancer_v1  ageSexBmi 0.002
```

*** EDIT ****
Below is the html from Chrome's inspect element option:

```
    <html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="lib/htmlwidgets-1.3/htmlwidgets.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/datatables-css-0.0.0/datatables-crosstalk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/datatables-binding-0.5/datatables.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/dt-core-1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/dt-core-1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.extra.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/dt-core-1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/crosstalk-1.0.0/css/crosstalk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/crosstalk-1.0.0/js/crosstalk.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body style="background-color: white; margin: 0px; padding: 40px;">
    <div id="htmlwidget_container">
      <div id="htmlwidget-3a36880ad35572a39f25" style="width:960px;height:500px;" class="datatables html-widget html-widget-static-bound"><div id="DataTables_Table_0_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer"><div class="dataTables_length" id="DataTables_Table_0_length"><label>Show <select name="DataTables_Table_0_length" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" class=""><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select> entries</label></div><div id="DataTables_Table_0_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Search:<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0"></label></div><table class="display dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_0" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
      <thead>
        <tr role="row"><th class="details-control sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=" "> </th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="outcome.bestOf: activate to sort column ascending">outcome.bestOf</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="study1.bestOf: activate to sort column ascending">study1.bestOf</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="study2.bestOf: activate to sort column ascending">study2.bestOf</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="study3.bestOf: activate to sort column ascending">study3.bestOf</th></tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class=" details-control" style="cursor: pointer;">⊕</td><td>HeartAttack</td><td>1e-06</td><td>0.05</td><td>0.005</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class=" details-control" style="cursor: pointer;">⊕</td><td>Cancer</td><td>0.05</td><td>0.01</td><td>0.002</td></tr></tbody></table><div class="dataTables_info" id="DataTables_Table_0_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries</div><div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="DataTables_Table_0_paginate"><a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="DataTables_Table_0_previous">Previous</a><span><a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></span><a class="paginate_button next disabled" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0" id="DataTables_Table_0_next">Next</a></div></div></div>
    </div>
    <script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-3a36880ad35572a39f25">{"x":{"filter":"none","data":[["1","2"],["&oplus;","&oplus;"],["HeartAttack","Cancer"],["1e-06","0.05"],["0.05","0.01"],["0.005","0.002"],[{"studyName":["study1","study1","study2","study2","study3"],"outcome":["heartAttack_v1","heartAttack_v2","heartAttack_v1","heartAttack_v2","heartAttack_v1"],"model":["ageSex","ageSexBmi","ageSex","ageSexBmi","ageSex"],"pvalue":["1e-06","0.001","0.05","0.2","0.005"]},{"studyName":["study1","study1","study2","study2","study3"],"outcome":["cancer_v1","cancer_v2","cancer_v1","cancer_v2","cancer_v1"],"model":["ageSex","ageSex","ageSexBmi","ageSex","ageSexBmi"],"pvalue":["0.6","0.05","0.2","0.01","0.002"]}]],"container":"<table class=\"display\">\n  <thead>\n    <tr>\n      <th> <\/th>\n      <th> <\/th>\n      <th>outcome.bestOf<\/th>\n      <th>study1.bestOf<\/th>\n      <th>study2.bestOf<\/th>\n      <th>study3.bestOf<\/th>\n      <th>data<\/th>\n    <\/tr>\n  <\/thead>\n<\/table>","options":{"columnDefs":[{"visible":false,"targets":[0,6]},{"orderable":false,"className":"details-control","targets":1},{"orderable":false,"targets":0}],"order":[],"autoWidth":false,"orderClasses":false},"callback":"function(table) {\n\n                   table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});\n                   \n                   // Format data object (the nested table) into another table\n                   var format = function(d) {\n                   if(d != null){ \n                   var result = ('<table id=\"child_' + d[2] + '_' + d[3] + '_' + d[4] + '_' + d[5] + '\">').replace('.','_') + '<thead><tr>'\n                   for (var col in d[6]){\n                   result += '<th>' + col + '<\/th>'\n                   }\n                   result += '<\/tr><\/thead><\/table>'\n                   return result\n                   }else{\n                   return '';\n                   }\n                   }\n                   \n                   var format_datatable = function(d) {\n                   var dataset = [];\n                   for (i = 0; i < + d[6]['cohort'].length; i++) {\n                   var datarow = [];\n                   for (var col in d[6]){\n                   datarow.push(d[6][col][i])\n                   }\n                   dataset.push(datarow)\n                   }\n                   var subtable = $(('table#child_' + d[2] + '_' + d[3] + '_' + d[4] + '_' + d[5]).replace('.','_')).DataTable({\n                   'data': dataset,\n                   'autoWidth': true, \n                   'deferRender': true, \n                   'info': false, \n                   'lengthChange': false, \n                   'ordering': true, \n                   'paging': false, \n                   'scrollX': false, \n                   'scrollY': false, \n                   'searching': false \n                   });\n                   };\n                   \n                   table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {\n                   var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));\n                   if (row.child.isShown()) {\n                   row.child.hide();\n                   td.html('&oplus;');\n                   } else {\n                   row.child(format(row.data())).show();\n                   td.html('&CircleMinus;');\n                   format_datatable(row.data())\n                   }\n                   });\n}"},"evals":["callback"],"jsHooks":[]}</script>
    <script type="application/htmlwidget-sizing" data-for="htmlwidget-3a36880ad35572a39f25">{"viewer":{"width":450,"height":350,"padding":15,"fill":true},"browser":{"width":960,"height":500,"padding":40,"fill":false}}</script>


    </body></html>
```

**** EDIT 2 **** With changes suggested by Stéphane Laurent

```
allresults <- list(c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study1", "heartAttack_v1", "ageSex", 1e-6), 
                   c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study1", "heartAttack_v2", "ageSexBmi", 0.001), 
                   c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study2", "heartAttack_v1", "ageSex", 0.05), 
                   c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study2", "heartAttack_v2", "ageSexBmi", "0.2"), 
                   c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study3", "heartAttack_v1", "ageSex", "0.005"), 
                   c( "Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study1", "cancer_v1", "ageSex", 0.6), 
                   c( "Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study1", "cancer_v2", "ageSex", 0.05), 
                   c("Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study2", "cancer_v1", "ageSexBmi", 0.2), 
                   c("Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study2", "cancer_v2", "ageSex", 0.01), 
                   c("Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study3", "cancer_v1", "ageSexBmi", 0.002))

df <- as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(allresults)))
colnames(df) <- c("outcome.bestOf", "study1.bestOf", "study2.bestOf", "study3.bestOf", "studyName", "outcome", "model", "pvalue")
rownames(df)<-NULL



# == Collapse to display top-result table, one row per outcome
nest_fields <- c("outcome.bestOf", "study1.bestOf", "study2.bestOf", "study3.bestOf") 
dt <- df %>%
  nest(-nest_fields)

# == Add (+) column
data <- dt %>% {bind_cols(data_frame(' ' = rep('&oplus;',nrow(.))),.)}

# == Get dynamic info and strings
# == code via: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/issues/9

nested_columns         <- which(sapply(data,class)=="list") %>% setNames(NULL)
not_nested_columns     <- which(!(seq_along(data) %in% c(1,nested_columns)))
not_nested_columns_str <- not_nested_columns %>% paste(collapse="] + '_' + d[") %>% paste0("d[",.,"]")

# == The callback
# == Turn rows into child rows and remove from parent
callback <- paste0("
                   table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});

                   // Format data object (the nested table) into another table
                   var format = function(d) {
                   if(d != null){ 
                   var result = ('<table id=\"child_' + ",not_nested_columns_str," + '\">').replace('/\\./g','_') + '<thead><tr>'
                   for (var col in d[",nested_columns,"]){
                   result += '<th>' + col + '</th>'
                   }
                   result += '</tr></thead></table>'
                   return result
                   }else{
                   return '';
                   }
                   }

                   var format_datatable = function(d) {
                   var dataset = [];
                   for (i = 0; i < + d[",nested_columns,"]['studyName'].length; i++) {
                   var datarow = [];
                   for (var col in d[",nested_columns,"]){
                   datarow.push(d[",nested_columns,"][col][i])
                   }
                   dataset.push(datarow)
                   }
                   var subtable = $(('table#child_' + ",not_nested_columns_str,").replace('/\\./g','_') ).DataTable({
                   'data': dataset,
                   'autoWidth': true, 
                   'deferRender': true, 
                   'info': false, 
                   'lengthChange': false, 
                   'ordering': true, 
                   'paging': false, 
                   'scrollX': false, 
                   'scrollY': false, 
                   'searching': false 
                   });
                   };

                   table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
                   var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
                   if (row.child.isShown()) {
                   row.child.hide();
                   td.html('&oplus;');
                   } else {
                   row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                   td.html('&CircleMinus;');
                   format_datatable(row.data())
                   }
                   });"
                  )


# == the Display DT
datatable(
  data,
  escape = FALSE,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0,nested_columns) ), # Hide row numbers and nested columns
      list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1) # turn first column into control column
    )
  ),
  callback = JS(callback)
)
```

Comment: Hej, could you add what is the output HTML / JS / CSS that you get after running that R code? It would be easier to debug

Comment: Can you clarify a little more what output you are asking for?  I included a screenshot of the data table and the tibble info.  I am not writing out a file at the moment, the script is running in Rstudio so the screenshot is just from that viewer

Comment: So, the R code generates some HTML and javascript (the view is basically that) if you could write it somewhere the output (not the image, but actually the code) it will be very helpful to figure out the problem

Comment: The code box scrolls, are you referring to this call at very bottom? ` # == the Display DT
datatable(
  data,
  escape = FALSE,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0,nested_columns) ), # Hide row numbers and nested columns
      list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1) # turn first column into control column
    )
  ),
  callback = JS(callback)
)`

Comment: Sorry for returning late. No, I refer to the web code (the UI code) generated in the `callback <- paste0( ... )` just before the data table. Because it seems that your R code is correct, but your HTML / JavaScript is not

Comment: When I open the table in my browser, and look at the javascript developer view I get the following message:  ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at format_datatable (eval at window.HTMLWidgets.evaluateStringMember (htmlwidgets.js:735), <anonymous>:21:53)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.eval (eval at window.HTMLWidgets.evaluateStringMember (htmlwidgets.js:735), <anonymous>:50:20)
    at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLTableElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)```

Comment: Oks, looks like a JavaScript problem then, could you please :

Open the browser -> Inspect the code and copy paste in your question all the information (it should have some HTML and some Javascript code in there)

Comment: alright, updated the question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues.

```
d[",nested_columns,"]['cohort'].length
```

There's no `cohort` column. Replace with

```
d[",nested_columns,"]['studyName'].length
```

The other issue is the replacement of the dots with underscores:

```
var result = ('<table id=\"child_' + ",not_nested_columns_str," + '\">').replace('.','_') + '<thead><tr>'
```

This replaces only the first dot. Change to

```
var result = ('<table id=\"child_' + ",not_nested_columns_str," + '\">').replace('/\\./g','_') + '<thead><tr>'
```

Also here:

```
var subtable = $(('table#child_' + ",not_nested_columns_str,").replace('.','_')).DataTable({
```

[image]

Full code:

```
library(DT)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

# == Create dataframe with results to summarize
allresults <- list(c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study1", "heartAttack_v1", "ageSex", 1e-6), 
                   c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study1", "heartAttack_v2", "ageSexBmi", 0.001), 
                   c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study2", "heartAttack_v1", "ageSex", 0.05), 
                   c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study2", "heartAttack_v2", "ageSexBmi", "0.2"), 
                   c("HeartAttack", 1e-6, 0.05, 0.005, "study3", "heartAttack_v1", "ageSex", "0.005"), 
                   c( "Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study1", "cancer_v1", "ageSex", 0.6), 
                   c( "Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study1", "cancer_v2", "ageSex", 0.05), 
                   c("Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study2", "cancer_v1", "ageSexBmi", 0.2), 
                   c("Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study2", "cancer_v2", "ageSex", 0.01), 
                   c("Cancer",  0.05, 0.01, 0.002, "study3", "cancer_v1", "ageSexBmi", 0.002))

df <- as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(allresults)))
colnames(df) <- c("outcome.bestOf", "study1.bestOf", "study2.bestOf", "study3.bestOf", "studyName", "outcome", "model", "pvalue")
rownames(df)<-NULL

# == Collapse to display top-result table, one row per outcome
nest_fields <- c("outcome.bestOf", "study1.bestOf", "study2.bestOf", "study3.bestOf") 
dt <- df %>%
  nest(-nest_fields)

# == Add (+) column
data <- dt %>% {bind_cols(data_frame(' ' = rep('&oplus;',nrow(.))),.)}

# == Get dynamic info and strings
# == code via: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/issues/9

nested_columns         <- which(sapply(data,class)=="list") %>% setNames(NULL)
not_nested_columns     <- which(!(seq_along(data) %in% c(1,nested_columns)))
not_nested_columns_str <- not_nested_columns %>% paste(collapse="] + '_' + d[") %>% paste0("d[",.,"]")

# == The callback
# == Turn rows into child rows and remove from parent
callback <- paste0("
                   table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});

                   // Format data object (the nested table) into another table
                   var format = function(d) {
                   if(d != null){ 
                   var result = ('<table id=\"child_' + ",not_nested_columns_str," + '\">').replace(/\\./g,'_') + '<thead><tr>'
                   for (var col in d[",nested_columns,"]){
                   result += '<th>' + col + '</th>'
                   }
                   result += '</tr></thead></table>'
                   return result
                   }else{
                   return '';
                   }
                   }

                   var format_datatable = function(d) {
                   var dataset = [];
                   for (var i = 0; i < + d[",nested_columns,"]['studyName'].length; i++) {
                   var datarow = [];
                   for (var col in d[",nested_columns,"]){
                   datarow.push(d[",nested_columns,"][col][i])
                   }
                   dataset.push(datarow)
                   }
                   var subtable = $(('table#child_' + ",not_nested_columns_str,").replace(/\\./g,'_')).DataTable({
                   'data': dataset,
                   'autoWidth': true, 
                   'deferRender': true, 
                   'info': false, 
                   'lengthChange': false, 
                   'ordering': true, 
                   'paging': false, 
                   'scrollX': false, 
                   'scrollY': false, 
                   'searching': false 
                   });
                   };

                   table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
                   var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
                   if (row.child.isShown()) {
                   row.child.hide();
                   td.html('&oplus;');
                   } else {
                   row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                   td.html('&CircleMinus;');
                   format_datatable(row.data())
                   }
                   });"
                  )


# == the Display DT
datatable(
  data,
  escape = FALSE,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0,nested_columns) ), # Hide row numbers and nested columns
      list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1) # turn first column into control column
    )
  ),
  callback = JS(callback)
)
```

Comment: I edited the post with the 3 changes to the javascript callback you suggested, but the child rows still aren't appearing.  Did I misinterpret your answer?  - Thanks

Comment: @alexhli Weird, I don't see what else I changed. I have just edited my answer to include the full code, can you try it ? It works for me.

Comment: It works!  I had to restart my Rstudio for some reason.  Thanks for the attention and detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

### Future proofing

Building on the superb answer by @StéphaneLaurent, here are some changes to make it 2020-proof:

1. All input must be named for `nest()` these days, so replace `nest(-nest_fields)` with `nest(data=(-nest_fields))`
2. `data.frame()` gives an error and should be replaced with `tibble()` in this line: `data <- dt %>% { bind_cols(data.frame(' ' = rep('&oplus;', nrow(.))), .) }`
3. The line `nested_columns <- which(sapply(data,class)=="list") %>% setNames(NULL)` doesn't work any longer because, for some reason, the class of the nested tibble is no longer `list`, but instead two classes: `"vctrs_list_of"` and `"vctrs_vctr"`. We need to add an extra `sapply()` to deal with double classes, like so: `nested_columns <- which(sapply(sapply(data,class), function(x) "vctrs_list_of" %in% x)) %>% setNames(NULL)`

### Edge case (FWIW)

On a separate note – as I just spent 3 hours figuring this out – the above solution dynamically creates unique `table id`s in the JavaScript callback by concatenating all values in the row, separated by `_`, like so:

```
"var result = ('<table id=\"child_' + ",not_nested_columns_str," + '\">').replace(/\\./g,'_') + '<thead><tr>'"
```

If, like in my case, any of the cells in the row contain a string, which contain blank spaces, the id doesn't work, and it fails *silently* (it will simply not display values in the child row, only the headers).

My workaround is to have a unique ID column (`id`) in your original data.frame and to use that for `table id` instead. This requires adding the line `id_column <- which(names(data)=="id")`, and to change the bit in the JS callback like so:

```
"var result = ('<table id=\"child_' + d[",id_column,"] + '\">') + '<thead><tr>'"
```

Make sure to also adjust the JS callback bit where it creates `subtable`, since it does that using the `table id`:

```
"var subtable = $(('table#child_' + d[",id_column,"])).DataTable({"
```

NB. We can omit the `.replace()` bit in JS if we assure the id column only contains numbers.

Finally, if you want to hide the ID column in the final output, you can always add it to the options list, like so:

```
list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0,id_column,nested_columns) ), # Hide row numbers and nested columns`
```

Hopefully this saves someone else a bunch of time figuring it out!