# DataTables for R: "warning: `dim<-.vctrs_list_of()` not supported"

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I'm new to DataTables but have been amazed at its power, and have managed to create a few different tables and use them in a Shiny dashboard. Currently I'm trying to implement [this table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56120992/1092247), and have managed to do so after updating a bit of the code (see my own answer in the thread).

However, when inserting the final table into Shiny, like so...

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table = DT::renderDataTable({final_table})
  }
)
```

...I get the error `DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - 'dim<-.vctrs_list_of()' not supported.` Simply running `final_table` in RStudio produces the DataTable exactly as intended. Using the identically-named functions from `shiny` instead of `DT` returns a blank page.

I recognise the `vctrs_list_of` from one of the changes I had to make to the linked answer above (which was because `tidyr`'s `nest()` these days returns a nested column of class `vctrs_list_of` rather than `list`), so I guess there's something happening there.

However, using 'inspect element' I only see an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` JS error, which links to some obscure line in the massive DataTables JS script. The warning is not included in DataTables' documentation.

Any leads/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by forcing the class of the column in question from `vctrs_list_of` to `list`, simply by running `class(table$data) <- "list"`.

(Note: it required some changes to the JavaScript code of the linked example, since the column, now being `list`, had a slightly different structure.)

If anyone has a more precise explanation of what's happening here, would love to hear!